# How to use JWT for authentication in apache jena through HttpOp.java?

Tags: java, authentication, jena, apache-jena

I want to use **JWT** for authentication purpose for information exchange. According to the [JWT documentation](http://jwt.io) documentation, I have to add a header with field `Authorization : Bearer <token>` .

But in `apache jena` in `HttpOp.java` which `execHttpGet(...) method` I have to execute and what values of parameters I have to pass and where this header value `Authorization : Bearer <token>` I have to put ?

Why `HttpAuthenticator` in parameter of `executeHttpGet(...)` if it is `interface`?

Please response in simple terms , **I am not clear with** `HttpContext` , `HttpClient` , `HttpAuthenticator`.

Comment: I think question remains a Question :P